# How to get defined functions parameternames in PHP

Tags: php, function, parameters, get

I'm making an MVC-framework in PHP and am trying to recreate a beautiful feature from C# MVC 4. As follows:

```
class MyController
{
    public function MyFunction ($id, $name)
    {
        // Do something with id and name
    }
}
```

This function is an example function inside a controller. The id and name should contain the same as $_GET["id"] etc. To make it so i need to know the names of the function parameters from outside of the function.

Pseudocode:

```
$myController = new MyController();
$controllerArgumentsArray = functionToGetArgumentNames($myController->MyFunction());

print_r($controllerArgumentsArray)
array([0] = "id", [1] = "name")
```

From here I could now use the "call_user_func_array" to set the values in the function to its correct relatives in the $_GET variable.

Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: http://php.net/manual/class.reflectionmethod.php

```
class Foo
{
  public function bar($id) {
  }
}

$r = new ReflectionMethod('Foo', 'bar');
print_r($r->getParameters());

/*
Array
(
    [0] => ReflectionParameter Object
        (
            [name] => id
        )

)
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

To get this info :)

Comment: That's only from inside of the function. But thanks anyway :)